# Alternative to commands library in python 2.7 and 3.6

Tags: python

My original question is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164551/starting-a-process-with-a-shell-possible-injection-detected-security-issue

Didn't receive any answers there, so cross-posting it here.

I just want to know an alternative to
`import commands`
`commands.getoutput()`

the commands library.
 Is there a way of doing this using something like os or subprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commands` is deprecated and should be replaced with `subprocess` calls. A replacement for `commands.getoutput()` is `subprocess.Popen().communicate()`:

```
import subprocess
import shlex


command = shlex.split('/bin/ls -l -a -h')
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

`bandit` will probably still throw you a low severity issue because you still use `subprocess` which is unsafe per se as anything invoking a shell, but this is inavoidable. See the remaining warning as a reminder on a potential insecurity in your code - depending on what you actually are calling in a shell, you have to do the checking yourself - is it a command hardcoded in a string constant, or a user input, or something variable depending on calling code? In any case, it's always advised to do the sanitization, Python has [`pipes` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html) for that.

Comment: I am able to use it, could please tell how to find the package version of shlex and subprocess? I'm unable to do it using `pip list | grep shlex` and `python -c "import ushlex; print(ushlex.__version__)"
`

Comment: I want to intall them via `pip install -r packages.txt`

Comment: Both [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) (since Python 1.5.2) and [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) (since Python 2.4) are part of Python's standard library, so you don't have to install them separately.

Comment: what is the purpose `command = shlex.split('/bin/ls -l -a -h')` does subprocess require the command to follow a particular format?

Comment: Yes, `subprocess` expects the command to be passed as a list of strings, so `ls -l` would be called as `subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'])`. This what `shlex.split` does: `shlex.split('ls -l')` returns `['ls', '-l']`.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" way would be `subprocess`, as per hoefling's answer, but some more modern ways are available if you don't mind using external libraries.

[envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy) has been deprecated by [delegator](https://github.com/kennethreitz/delegator.py) and here's how it looks:

```
In [1]: import delegator

In [2]: print delegator.run('pwd').out
/home/vince
```

I installed it with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/delegator.py.git@v0.1.0
```

Comment: thanks. basically I am looking for an alternative to `commands.getoutput()` is all.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

commands = subprocess
```

Leave rest code same, it will work as it is

Comment: It does! this is great :)